# How to close all child threads using C++

Tags: c++, qt

My windows/QT application is not exiting consistently.

After the object clean up, I am trying to delete the QProcess object. But it's not cleaning up the process and it can be shown in the task manager.

```
    delete process;
    process = 0;
```

I think delete process is not working because some threads are running at the background. I want to ensure that all threads are closed gracefully, so the process will exit.

Please let me know the right way to do this.

Comment: Iterate over your collection of threads and `join` each of them.

Comment: Kerrek, you mean using windows api and do this. can you suggest the api names. thanks

Comment: No, no Windows API. Just use the Qt threading model. Surely you have kept a record of all your threads somewhere?!

Answer (score 0):

The task manager does not show your QProcess object, and deleting that object will not affect the task manager. If there is still code running in your process, the process will continue to exist according to the OS.

If you *really* want to exit the process, you can call the Win32 function [`ExitProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Just make sure you've saved everything you want to.

Qt will normally exit the process when all your threads stop running.

Comment: Greg,  somebody in my team suggested that Qprocess not exiting, so make sure before deleting the object use the windows api and close all threads.. I don't know that is the right way.. please advice

Answer (score 0):

One problem may be that the QProcess object doesn't represent a child thread, it represents an independent process, you probably want to use the [QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html) object.

With the QThread object you can use some combination of the quit, exit, wait, and terminate depending on the exact content of you child thread, check the documentation for the differences.